# MANTER ACTIVITY AO MINIMIZAR

Tags: android, android-activity

Como faço pra meu app manter a activity atual quando minimizo e maximizo a janela? Notei que todo app que faço, se eu minimizar e maximizar ele volta pra acitivity inicial, principalmente em apps q necessitam de login isso não pode ocorrer, já pensou? Toda vez maximizar ter q fazer login novamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você está trabalhando com múltiplas activities, uma forma de solucionar este problema é ter uma activity "vazia" como inicial. Ela só conteria uma lógica para verificar se o usuário está logado ou não, e então redireciona para a activity correta.