# Android Kotlin - App minimiza mas ao maximizar o app recomeça inicio

Tags: android, kotlin

Olá, tenho um app que ao minimizar e maximizar recomeça na activity.MAIN, toda vez. Achei essa pergunta porem a resposta nao soluciona o problema [MANTER ACTIVITY AO MINIMIZAR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273726/manter-activity-ao-minimizar)
pois o usuário que está na minha App, perde o foco de onde está no momento, ex. para chegar a determinado lugar dentro do App, o usuário tem que passar por uma série de filtros e quando recomeça o usuário tem que refazer todos esses filtros novamente. No Logcat não mostra nada, nem verbose.

Como faço para manter na mesma activity, e não perder os dados já filtrados.

Comment: Veja sobre `Instance states` em: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#instance-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri que não tem nada haver com Activity Lifecycle, e sim o que faz isso acontecer é o próprio sistema android instalado em um tablet Hyunday - API 7.1.1 em qualquer outro dispositivo android(emuladores), LG-K10, Samsung(fisicos)  funciona perfeitamente. Neste tablet qualquer aplicativo que está instalado nele acontece a mesma coisa. Desde o Google Chrome, Drive, ou qualquer outro app instalado pelo Google Play. Fiz todos reviews e nenhuma solução,nem o Android Studio mostra um log sobre o erro, indicando que o App está correndo normalmente, então o O.S. do tablet que reinicia qualquer App ao tentar minimizar e maximizar.

Já pedi suporte para a própria fabricante, isso é um bug na sistema que vem junto ao tablet e não relacionado ao Aplicativo ou qualquer outro App.